# Reference Request: Products of Compact-Open Topologies

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307032/products-and-the-compact-open-topology), it is shown that if $X$ is a locally-compact Hausdorff space then $C(X,Y\times Z)\cong C(X,Y)\times C(X,Z)$ are homeomorphic when equipped with the compact-open topologies.  I'm having trouble finding this in a book/ original paper.  Does anyone know a reference?

Comment: Is $X$ Hausdorff too?

Comment: Indeed, I made the adjustment.

Comment: Are you interested in a reference or a proof? I feel the proof should be elementary. As to reference, you could start by investigating the references of these two entries https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Exponential_law_(in_topology) https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces (the exponential law of your equation is $(Y\times Z)^X = Y^X \times Z^X$, but its not listed in these entries)

Comment: It is true for arbitrary $X, Y, Z$. In Dugundji, James, "Topology", Allyn and Bacon Inc., Boston, 1966, it occurs as an exercise to Section 5 of Chapter XII.

Comment: Perfect.  I'd accept that as an aswer if you would like to post it :)

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is true for arbitrary $X,Y,Z$. In

> Dugundji, James, "Topology", Allyn and Bacon Inc., Boston, 1966

it occurs as an exercise to Section 5 of Chapter XII.